# The locale of morphisms vs a morphism to an ultrapower?

Tags: ct.category-theory, model-theory, locales, ultrapowers

I'm fixing some type of structure $\Sigma$ (possibly multi-sorted, with functions symbols and relation symbols, though assuming it single sorted with only relation symbols wouldn't change anything). Let $A$ and $B$ be two $\Sigma$-structure. Is there a connection between the following to notion :

1. The locale $[A,B]_\Sigma$ classyfing morphisms of $\Sigma$-structure form $A$ to $B$.
2. Morphism of $\Sigma$-structure from $A$ to an ultrapower of $B$.

Intuitively both are way to make formal the idea that "their ought to be a morphism from $A$ to $B$, up to potential (infinite) cardinality obstruction"

As a first concrete step, the question would be:

**Is it true that $[A,B]_\Sigma \neq \varnothing$ if and only if there exists a morphism of $\Sigma$-structure from $A$ to an ultrapower of $B$ ?**

But Ideally (and if the above is indeed true) I would like something more concrete that explain how to go back and forth between a morphism to an ultrapower and some sort of witness that the locale is non-trivial (like maybe points of a compactification or something like this).

If you are a model theorist, I guess you can replace $[A,B]_\Sigma \neq \varnothing$ by the existence of a forcing extention of the base set theory in which there is a map from $A$ to $B$ and that should give something that can be translated back to my question.

I'm giving an explicit example in order to fix the idea :

Let $\Sigma$ be single sorted with a single binary relation $R$, and take $A$ and $B$ two $\Sigma$ structure where $R$ is interpreted as the relation $\neq$. Then $[A,B]_{\Sigma}$ is the classifying locale of injection from $A$ to $B$ wich is non trivial as soon as "$B$ is infinite or $|A| \leqslant |B| < \infty$ ". And this is also the condition under which (I'm assuming choice here) you will be able to get an injection from $A$ to some ultrapower of $B$.

Comment: My hunch is that there may be an answer to this question to be found by considering Makkai's theory of ultracategories. I'd suggest looking at Lurie's treatment of the subject for inspiration.

Comment: @TimCampion well, funny that you mention this : that question did arise while thinking about Ultracategories and Makkai conceptual completness. But I'm not entierely sure there is a concrete link. At lest I couldn't find one.

Comment: @SimonHenry, the existence of a homomorphism of $A$ into a reduced power of $B$ (quotient by a filter not necessarily ultrafilter) is equivalent to the existence of a pure homomorphism $B \to A$. If one takes elementary embeddings instead of homomorphisms, then an ultrapower is needed.

Comment: @godelian , Hi ! I don't know what "pure homomorphism" mean in this context and google doesn't give a clear answer. Can you clarify/give a pointer ?

Comment: @SimonHenry A homomorphism $B \to A$ is pure (also called $\omega$-pure) if it reflects the validity of positive existential sentences with parameters from $B$, i.e., if $A \models \exists \overline{x}\phi(\overline{x}, \overline{c})$ implies $B \models \exists \overline{x}\phi(\overline{x}, \overline{c})$ for $\phi$ a conjunction of atomic formulas.

Comment: The version for elementary embeddings and ultrapowers is proven in Lemma 9.1 and 9.2 in Kochen's paper "Ultraproducts in the theory of models". I believe the same proof works for the pure homomorphisms and reduced powers.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the same as the notion of an $\omega$-pure monomorphism of $\Sigma$-structures as found in, say, Adamek and Rosicky's book.

Comment: Just to follow up on @godelian’s notion of pure — this is *ω-pure* in the sense of the Adámek and Rosicky book, Def 2.27.

Comment: Yes, it's the same notion. I read first Makkai calling it pure. By the way, looking again at Lemma 9.2 in Kochen, the morphism from B to A is given, its pureness is equivalent to the existence of the homomorphism into the reduced power. Lemma 9.1 gives the equivalence with $B$ and $A$ being elementarily equivalent (which by Keisler-Shelah is the same as having isomorphic ultrapowers).

Comment: Yes the result in Kochen's paper presupose we have a morphism in the other direction, so I don't really see how to relate to my question, but maybe I'm missing something...

Comment: "If you are a model theorist, I guess you can replace $[A,B]_\Sigma \neq \varnothing$ by the existence of a forcing extention of the base set theory in which there is a map from $A$ to $B$ and that should give something that can be translated back to my question." I don't think that's true, or at least if it is then your two conditions are highly different: if $B=\mathbb{N}$ and $A$ is a nontrivial ultrapower of $B$, then there are no homomorphisms from $A$ to $B$ in any forcing extension of the universe, but there are lots of homomorphisms from $A$ into an ultrapower of $B$ (e.g. $A$ itself).

Comment: @NoahSchweber Maybe we mean something different, but if you only consider $A$ and $B$ as sets with a relation imposing injectivity as I did in the exemple, there you can always consider a forcing extention that collaps the cardinality of $A$ to being countable and there are going to be maps from $A$ to $B$ in that extention as both are juste infinite countable sets.

Comment: @SimonHenry Sorry, I am treating them as ordered (in the sense of $<$, not $\le$) semirings here. Then forcing cannot add any homomorphisms from a nonstandard model to the standard model.

Comment: @NoahSchweber : Oh. Thanks. I think that does answer my question. It seems like in this case the locale of morphisms is indeed trivial.

Comment: @SimonHenry I've posted an attempt at an answer; since I'm unfamiliar with locales, though, I'm not sure it's right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe there are situations where the relevant locale is trivial, but there are many homomorphisms post-ultrapower.

For example, take $\mathcal{B}=(\mathbb{N};<)$ and let $\mathcal{A}$ be a nontrivial ultrapower of $\mathcal{B}$. There are no genuine homomorphisms from $\mathcal{A}$ to $\mathcal{B}$, and moreover this remains true in any forcing extension (since no homomorphism of strict linear orders can "move" infinitely-far-apart points to within finite distance of each other); per the comments, I *think* this means that the relevant locale is trivial too, but I'm not very familiar with locales. On the other hand, we trivially have lots of homomorphisms from $\mathcal{A}$ into ultrapowers of $\mathcal{B}$.

---

EDIT: Well after the fact, I've run into a result which while not directly related to this question may still be of similar interest, so I've decided to mention it here. John Bell's paper [*Isomorphism of structures in $S$-toposes*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2273748). Bell shows that for structures $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B}$ in the same language, the following are equivalent:

- $\mathcal{A}\cong\mathcal{B}$ in some forcing extension (that is, $\mathcal{A}\cong_{\infty\omega}\mathcal{B}$ by earlier results).
- $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ "become isomorphic" in some topos over $\bf{Set}$ (which Bell calls "$S$").

I think this result adds some nuance to the observations above, although I'm a bit out of my element here.

Comment: Adding $+$ to the structure, I'm completely convinced this is a counter-example. I don't quite know without $+$, but maybe it is as well.

Comment: @SimonHenry I think even without $+$ this should work if the forcing/locale connection holds. The point is that if $f$ is a homomorphism of strict linear orders, then $f$ cannot map infinitely far apart points to finitely far apart points (since $f$ must be injective). But $\mathcal{B}$ is "locally finite" (= any two points are finitely far apart; I think I'm actually misusing the term?) while $\mathcal{A}$ is not.

Comment: Ah yes, that seems right. Thanks you !

Comment: @SimonHenry I've folded that into the answer.